# Calling method inside .so shared library on android studio

Tags: java, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android-studio-2.1

I need some help to use the method "callMethod()" inside ".so" (shared library) in android studio.

My android studio version is 2.1.3.

I created jniLibs folder in "src/main/".
Then I created three folders inside jniLibs folder: (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86).
Then I put the .so library inside every mentioned folder.
After that, I updated the build.gradle as follows:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','.so'])
```

In the MainActivity java class I wrote this:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("SharedLibAndroid");
    }
```

After that I don't know what should I do.

How do I call the method `callMethod()` from the .so library?

I searched a lot but I did't see full example how to do that.

I've added to my project new class and native method like below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public class Test1Cpp {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("Cpp");
}

public native String callMethod();
}
```

Then I can call the method inside .so shared library.

I faced another problem, which is my .so library didn't work with all platform mobiles.

The error is:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
> "/data/app/com.mysecondtestapp-1/lib/arm/libCpp.so" has
> unexpected e_machine: 3

So, how to convert my .so library to work on all platform mobiles?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the library does load, otherwise you would get an exception, and I guess you would have mentioned it. So you need to declare the native method you would like to use from the library, and then call it. You can see a simple example here: [Sample: hello-jni](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html)

The sample source code may be found here: [Hello JNI](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni).

Comment: Thanks yakobom for your answering, but I didn't see in your example how to load and use the shared library.
In other hand, I need some details how to link and use the shared library in android studio.

Comment: As I said, since you did not indicate a loading error, I assumed you have no problem with loading. Anyway - the link I gave you guides through everything you need to do, but if you want to look at the working example, look at the source code (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Many thanks @yakobom for your follow up,
I saw the hello-jni sample, and the static { System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); } but I didn't see the generated shared library (.so),
When I delete the .c file, the project didn't run, and it gave me the error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.stringFromJNI() (tried Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI and Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI__)

So, it maybe depends on the .c file not on .so library

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow things like this - if you still have problems, I suggest you update your post properly with all relevant details, so we could try to help you out.

Comment: I've updated my question, would you help me @yakobom

Comment: e_machine 3 means EM_386 architecture, which is obviously not what you want. I would suspect you are missing something in the make file (Android.mk) - perhaps LOCAL_ARM_MODE, or maybe APP_ABI in the Application.mk